# TextFormatter throws exception when binding (bidirectional) to a null string

Tags: java, javafx, binding

**Edit**
Apparently this is a bug. The report I've made can be found [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8147827). As @James_D noted, this is not an issue with the binding, but it is enough to set the text to null after it has been set to a non-null value.

---

I am having troubles with JavaFX `TextFormatter`. I want to limit the length of text in a text field to 10 characters, but I find the if the text property was bound to a non-null value, and then is unbound and rebound to a null value, the text formatter throws an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end

upon calling `TextFormatter.Change#getControlNewText`, which is weird, because if anything I would have expected a null reference exception.

I attach a simple code for a complete example exhibiting this problem. If there is anything I'm doing wrong please let me know

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Model m;
    private int num = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(change -> change.getControlNewText().length() > 10 ? null : change));
        Button b = new Button("Click!");
        b.setOnAction(ev -> {
                    if (m != null) {
                        tf.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(m.nameProperty());
                    }

                    m = new Model();
                    if (num % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Setting foo");
                        m.setName("foo");
                    }
                    num++;

                    tf.textProperty().bindBidirectional(m.nameProperty());
                }
        );
        VBox vb = new VBox(tf, b);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vb));
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    public class Model {
        private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

In this code there is a `TextField` with a `TextFormatter` rejecting all changed which result in a string of length>10. When the button is clicked a new `Model` object is created, and it's `name` property is bound to the `TextField`'s text property - not before the old `Model` is unbound. The model is alternating between being initialized with "foo" as name, or not being initialized with a name - that is - the name remains null.

Upon first clicking the button you should see the text being changed to "foo", and when next clicking the button the exception is thrown.

Comment: Well, it's a bug. But even if it worked, this code seems a bit risky. You're setting up a bidirectional binding, which indicates that the two string properties should always hold the same value, however the text formatter is vetoing some changes to one of those properties. So potentially bad things could happen if this were "successful": what behavior would you expect from `m.setName("More than 10 characters");`?

Comment: Well, I don't expect it to happen :)  But you are correct that this is a problem. Still, it is unrelated to this bug. Do you know if this has been reported already? Or if there is a way I can get around it in the meantime?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I haven't been actively watching the bug reports for a while. Easy enough to do a quick search and submit a report if you don't find anything. I guess my point was that I was trying to figure out if there's a valid use case for attaching a (vetoing) formatter to a bidirectionally-bound text field; but you're right, this fails even if it doesn't veto at all: just as soon as you call `getControlNewText`.

Comment: Couldn't find a similar bug. I have submitted a report, but it will probably take a few days until it's filed, as is usual for "webbug" reports. I'll post here if it gets filed.

Comment: Can you avoid the model property being null as a workaround (use e.g. a zero-length string to initialize it)?

Comment: This is a workaround that could work for some cases. The problem is in my real program the model is written to a database, and I need to differentiate the cases when no value was ever entered (null value) and user entered empty string.

Comment: Actually, the binding is a bit of a red herring in terms of the bug. You can take out all references to the model entirely and just alternate between `setText("foo")` and `setText(null)` to see the exception occur.

Comment: You are correct! Maybe a better title for this would be "TextFormatter can't handle change to null if old value wasn't null". But now I have no way of conveying this information to the Java bug tracking system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug (it seems like the text formatter's filter doesn't properly handle the text being set to `null`). A possible workaround is to bind the value property of the text formatter, instead of the text property of the text field:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Model m;
    private int num = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TextField tf = new TextField();
        TextFormatter<String> textFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(
                TextFormatter.IDENTITY_STRING_CONVERTER, "", change -> 
            change.getControlNewText().length() > 10 ? null : change);

        tf.setTextFormatter(textFormatter);

        Button b = new Button("Click!");
        b.setOnAction(ev -> {
                    if (m != null) {
//                        tf.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(m.nameProperty());
                       textFormatter.valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(m.nameProperty());
                    }

                    m = new Model();
                    if (num % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Setting foo");
                        m.setName("foo");
                    } 
                    num++;

//                    tf.textProperty().bindBidirectional(m.nameProperty());
                    textFormatter.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(m.nameProperty());
                }
        );
        VBox vb = new VBox(tf, b);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vb));
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    public class Model {
        private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", "");

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I just figured it out and was about to post the same. It seems to be working perfectly.